# Help with general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation.
$$y''+20y=0$$

I'm not sure whether the general solution is:

$$A\cos(x\sqrt {20})+B\sin(x\sqrt {20})$$

or

$$A\sin(x(\sqrt {20}+C)) $$

if the latter how is this found?

Comment: I edited your question, but I don't know where the placement of the $x$ should be in the latter solution choice. OP, could you check again if you copied the solutions correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the auxilliary equation is $r^2+20=0$ which means that the complex roots are $r_1=0+2\sqrt{5}i$ and $r_2=0-2\sqrt{5}i$. General solution is
$$y=C_1e^{0x}\cos 2\sqrt{5}x+C_2e^{0x}\sin 2\sqrt{5}x=C_1\cos 2\sqrt{5}x+C_2\sin 2\sqrt{5}x$$

Comment: Ok sweet thankyou, how would you go about solving y''+20y=100sin(a*x) when y(0)=0 and y'(0)=0, i get a reasonably unattractive solution.
I have y(t)=Acost($\sqrt 20$t)+Bsin($\sqrt 20$t)+(100/(20-w^2))sin(a*x) where a does not equal $\sqrt 20$ as I want no resonance (part of the question_

Comment: @Phun Then better ask it as a separate question.